# How to add external class files to a new java project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have 6 class files I want to add to the src folder of a new eclipse project I have created.

How can I go about doing so?

I tried copying a class file into the folder through the workspace but I cannot get view it in the project in eclipse.

Thanks,

Comment: you are talking about compiled files or java source files?

Comment: `File` -> `Import...`

Comment: Then that's .java files, not .class files. Just drag and drop them from a filemanager into your source folder.

Comment: and i cannot file -> import because it does not let me select the files from where they are located

Comment: ... and then hit F5 when the package explorer has the focus.

Comment: When you copied the file directly into the folder through the work space, did you refresh the relevant Project?

Comment: thanks everyone, did not realize I could just drag and drop

Comment: Have you tried coping contend of source code in your `.java` files, select `src` directory in `Project Explorer` and pressing `Ctrl+V`? This should also create correct package tree.

Answer (score 1):

If you just copy the Java source files in the `src` directory in your workspace folder, and then refresh the `src` folder in Eclipse, you'll be able to see the Java source files, or whatever files you copy as a matter of fact. You can use `F5` to refresh or Right Click and press refresh.